# Creating structs that satisfy an interface

Tags: go, struct, interface

I am creating a Go application that takes some data as bytes and then attempts to generate some state from that data. My application consists of a registry that holds a list of structs that implement a Transformer interface, an interface that contains certain methods for serializing and hashing data.

```
   // Transformer contains some sort of transform logic
   Transformer() {
        Unique() string
        common.Applicator
        common.Hasher
        common.Packer
    }
```

Here is one struct that implements the interface and it has the following field and the interface methods are all implemented.

```
// Balance implements the Transformer interface.
type Balance struct {
    From   string `json:"from"`
    To     string `json:"to"`
    Amount string `json:"amount"`
    Unqiue   string `json:"unique"`
}
```

The issue I'm having is the data comes in like this. Here I have balance which is the unique name of the struct that implements the Transformer interface and an array of values that correlate to the balance struct above.

```
`
    {
       "balance":[
          {
             "unique":"balance",
             "amount":21,
             "to":"JoeB"
          },
          {
             "unique":"balance",
             "amount":24,
             "to":"JohnDoe"
          }
       ]
    }
    `
```

I want to now cast all these JSON objects into new balance structs so I can store them all as a list of Transformer interface types. However, as I can register multiple types that implement the Transformer interface I need a way of working out what the type should be when I loop.

```
initialBytes := make(map[string][]interface{})
    err := s.Unmarshal(i, &initialBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for unique, model := range registry.Transforms {
        if values, ok := initialBytes[unique]; ok {
            for _, v := range values {
              // I need a way here of creating structs of type model

            }
        }
    }
```

In my loop above I check to see if the map entry of data is the same as the entry in my registry. If it is I want to then create new values with that data of the same type as the registry entry so they all implement my interface. As they are interface types I can't seem to use the struct methods for example if I had

```
func (b Balance) NewBalance(Unique string) *Balance {
    return &Balance{
        Unique: Unique,
    }
}
```

I only have access to the Transformer methods. Is there an approach I'm missing here for creating struct instances that satisfy an interface in a loop?

Comment: If you have a value of type `Transformer`, you'll only have access to the methods defined in that interface, unless you [type assert](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to the underlying type.

Comment: Use `map[string]json.RawMessage`, unmarshal just the keys, then based on the keys initialiaze the proper struct type slice, and finally unmarshal the associated `json.RawMessage` into it.

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/41zFfVlBgbg ?

Comment: If you add this as an answer I'll accept!